# How do I get the application name of a process in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, tasklist

I'm trying to search for running processes based on their application name in my Java application. I believe on Linux this is possible using "**ps -ef**" and then using grep to filter.

The output I get on Windows using **tasklist.exe /fo csv /nh** is

```
"java.exe","6132","Console","1","50,704 K"
"conhost.exe","2392","Console","1","4,384 K"
"cmd.exe","5400","Console","1","3,792 K"
"conhost.exe","5656","Console","1","4,336 K"
"tasklist.exe","3576","Console","1","5,816 K"
```

All Java processes are listed as "java.exe" and I cannot differentiate between two different applications. Is there a way to obtain the application name of a process via the terminal similar to how it is displayed in the task manager.

---

I have accepted vvtx's answer although it does not necessarily answer the question, it provides a solution for what I wanted to do. This only works for Java applications so if someone has a solution for obtaining application names that are not Java processes it would be greatly appreciated.

---

I am re-opening this question because the answer given only works if the user has a JDK installed, this may not necessarily be the case. The end-user could have only the JRE

Comment: It seems you're looking to read the command line of each java.exe process to see which file it's executing. This should work to start: `wmic process where name='java.exe' get commandline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Window's command line use:

```
jps -v
```

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, this provides an alternative solution which works nicely for me. Do you know if this works on linux/mac as it comes with the jdk?

Comment: yes it does, as you rightly said: it comes with JDK. :-)

Comment: I have come across an issue using this as it is only included with the JDK. As my application is for end-users, this will not work if they don't have the JDK installed, correct? In which case I need an alternative solution.

Comment: I have decided to use jps :) thanks for the suggestion.